# The order of actions (in the example sentence)

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

- I **talked** to her **before** she **had arrived**.

Could you make the order of actions clear in this sentence?

Comment: First they talked. After that, the arrival took place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **talking** happened **before** the **arrival**.

What might be confusing to you is the fact that the *arrived* is in past perfect, while the *talked* is in the simple past. The fact there's a past perfect in the sentence means that the sentence is somehow based in the past. For instance, it's a narration and the events described are earlier than the point reached in the narration. I don't know if it's a technical term, but I try to think of a time as the base time or reference time for a sentence.

Because the *talked* is simple past, you would normally expect that it happened at the reference time of the sentence, and the past perfect *had arrived* happened before it. However, the word *before* takes precedence over such grammatical cues, because it is more explicit.